# How elevator and ailerons affect attack and roll angles?

Tags: flight-controls, flight-dynamics

I was trying to model the flight of an aircraft and i need some function that expresses the change of attack and roll angle in function of the elevator and ailerons (respectively).

Does anyone have an idea of how is this function or where i can find some data to interpolate?

Thanks to all those ones that will help me!

Comment: The answer to this would be extremely variable based on the airfoils used for the wing & horizontal stabilizer. Pitch and roll rates achieved, and required, in an acrobatic aircraft would be highly undesirable in a basic trainer. Without narrowing the scope of the question, the only possible answer is, "it depends."

Comment: Although for a basic model, you could probably assume that roll rate is proportional to control deflection.

Comment: Section 6.1.1.1-8 of the [USAF DATCOM for stability and control](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/ADB072483) about trailing edge plain flaps should answer your question in a very good way.

Comment: The rate of change of attitude also depends strongly on airspeed (local to that control surface;  in a tight turn the outboard aileron has more authority than the inboard one, for example).